# I am trying to install numba by the command pip install numba, but it is showing some error? How to fix this problem?

Tags: python, installation, module, pip, numba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dws3D.png) The screenshot is attached below which contain error

Comment: Please post your output as text, no screenshots! And BTW it does not contain the actual error.

Comment: If you scroll down, it most likely mentions the actual, relevant, searchable error message. As of now your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have reps for making comments I am posting as an answer. I don't know the error but try the following as these are my guess of what might have caused the error. First, check what python version you have it should be between 3.7-3.9 then `pip install numba`.

If that fails the easiest way to install numba is by using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). Install anaconda if not installed. Then do `conda install numba` or `conda update numba`.